# Configuration and Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, viewmodel, web-config

I've been developing an application using asp.net MVC, and I have some configurations that influences in process of render a view. For example, a user can choose (in an configuration of system) if a field should appear for a management of records in an area of the system. So, I have an class called AppConfiguration has some properties to represent this configurations.

I guess I need to cache an object of AppConfiguration, and make a ViewModel base class and inherits from my viewmodel, for example:

```
public class BaseViewModel {
   public AppConfiguration Config { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentViewModel : BaseViewModel {
   public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

and make typed views using "DocumentViewModel" to check the properties if this kind of document is able to render or not ? is it works ? Or is there any other better way to do something like this ?

Thanks all and sorry for my english!

Cheers

Comment: Does the configuration data come from the DB or from the web.config?

Comment: It comes from Database... (by Nhibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you write an associated [metadata provider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) for your view model and then use [default templated views](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) in MVC 2.